# Non linear recursion of the form $a_{n+1} \leq b_{n} \cdot a_{n} + c_{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms

During my research I encountered the need to solve a non linear recursion of the form

$$a_{n+1} \leq b_{n} \cdot a_{n} + c_{n}$$
Where $b_n$ and $c_n$ are known. More specifically, I'm interested not in $a_n$ itself but in a bound for $a_n$, i.e., I need to find $M_n$ so that $|a_n| \leq M_n$.

I have tried to bound $|b_n| \leq b$ and $|c_n| \leq c$ and solve $a_{n+1} \leq b \cdot a_{n} + c$ but the results are not good enough.

Is there a way to solve such recursions? Would it help to assume that $b_n \rightarrow b$ and $c_n \rightarrow c$?

Comment: I doubt that there will be good bounds on $a_n$ in this very general setup. Are there any further restraints? Also, if $b_n=b$ and $c_n=c$ doesn't give sufficently good bounds, why do you think $b_n\to b$ and $c_n\to c$ will give better ones?

Comment: @RedundantAunt: Asymptotically it would be similar, but I am mostly interested in the beginning of the sequence.

Comment: If $|b_n| \leq \rho < 1$ and $|c_n|\leq c$ for all $n\in\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ then $|a_n| \leq \frac{c}{1-\rho}$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ (assuming $|a_1|$ satisfies that inequality).

Comment: How is your inequality a "recursion"?  Perhaps you have an actual recursion that determines $a_{n+1}$ in terms of previous quantities, but an inequality does not.  There must be more to the setup, which is necessary if you want "the beginning of the sequence".

Comment: Also, if you are only interested in the beginning of the sequence, then imposing a condition on convergence won't change anything. If you would specify the context a little bit, we might help you.

Comment: @hardmath: it might interest you to know that it is possible to "somehow" fix the boundaries of this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider first of all the recurrence with the equal sign
$$
x_{\,n + 1}  = b_{\,n} \,x_{\,n}  + c_{\,n} 
$$
then we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & x_{\,n + 1}  = b_{\,n} \,x_{\,n}  + c_{\,n}  = b_{\,n} \,b_{\,n - 1} x_{\,n - 1}  + \left( {c_{\,n}  + b_{\,n - 1} c_{\,n - 1} } \right) =  \cdots  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {b_{\,j} } } \right)x_{\,0}  + \left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {c_{\,k} \prod\limits_{k + 1\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {b_{\,j} } } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {b_{\,j} } } \right)x_{\,0}  + \prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {b_{\,j} } \left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {{{c_{\,k} } \over {\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,k} {b_{\,j} } }}} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = x_{\,0} \left( {\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {b_{\,j} } } \right)\left( {1 + \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {{{c_{\,k} /x_{\,0} } \over {\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,k} {b_{\,j} } }}} } \right) = f(n) \cr} 
$$

So are clear the conditions that the coefficients $b$ and $c$ should respect
for $x(n)$ to converge, and what is the influence of the starting point $x(0)$.
If you can express $b$ and $c$ as a function of their index, you might
be able and get a closed form for $f(n)$.

Now the original disequality can be expressed in multiplicative way 
or in a subtractive way
$$
\eqalign{
  & a_{\,n + 1}  \le x_{\,n + 1}  = \beta _{\,n + 1} \,x_{\,n + 1}  = \beta _{\,n + 1} b_{\,n} \,x_{\,n}  + \beta _{\,n + 1} c_{\,n} \quad \left| {\;\beta _{\,n + 1}  \le 1\left( {{\rm if}\;0 \le x_{\,n + 1} } \right)} \right.  \cr 
  & a_{\,n + 1}  \le x_{\,n + 1}  = \,x_{\,n + 1}  - \gamma _{\,n + 1}  = b_{\,n} \,x_{\,n}  + \left( {c_{\,n}  - \gamma _{\,n + 1} } \right)\quad \left| {\;0 \le \gamma _{\,n + 1} } \right. \cr} 
$$
and then you can evaluate the effect of the modified $b$'s and $c$'s on the above
formula.

To evaluate the starting of the sequence, and possibly also to grasp the convergence of it, 
it will be useful to graph some of the first lines $y_n(x)=b_nx+c_n$, together with the line 
$y=x$, and trace there the first steps.

We take an example to illustrate the procedure: let's put
$$
b_{\,n}  = \left( {n + 1} \right)/\left( {n + 3} \right)\quad c_{\,n}  = 10/\left( {n + 1} \right)
$$
which gives
$$
b_{\,\infty }  = 1_{\, - } \quad c_{\,\infty }  = 0_{\, + } 
$$
and
$$
\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,n} {b_{\,j} }  = {{2\left( {n + 1} \right)!} \over {\left( {n + 3} \right)!}} = {2 \over {\left( {n + 3} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }} = {2 \over {\left( {n + 3} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)}}
$$
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {{{c_{\,k} } \over {\prod\limits_{0\, \le \,j\, \le \,k} {b_{\,j} } }}}  = 5\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {{{\left( {k + 3} \right)\left( {k + 2} \right)} \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = 5\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {k + 4 + {2 \over {\left( {k + 1} \right)}}}  = 5\left( {{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)} \over 2} + 4\left( {n + 1} \right) + 2H(n + 1)} \right) \cr} 
$$

Therefore for $f(n)$ we obtain
$$
f(n) = {1 \over {\left( {n + 3} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)}}\left( {5\left( {n + 8} \right)\left( {n + 1} \right) + 20H(n + 1) + 2\,x_{\,0} } \right)
$$
which in the limit gives
$$
f(\infty ) = 5
$$

The sequence evolves as shown in this graph

[image: Lin_Rec_1]

At this point we can see that, taking the recurrence with the disequality
is equivalent to shift or rotate   **to the left** the line $y(x)$, and the graph helps to visualize
what that would mean.

Comment: Thanks! I need to see how can I adjust it to my $b_n,c_n$

Comment: @catch22: glad to help